# File exceeded size for git even though it's been shrunk to below the limit

Tags: git, github

I get this error when I try to push my branch up to Github:

```
remote: error: File ProjectFunctionalityVideo/Project0Video.mov is 299.46 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

I've now shrunk the file to 67MB, added and committed the file again but still get the error when I push. I guess the file size has been cached somewhere. How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a ~300MB version of your file in a previous commit. You should remove any non-pushed previous commits.

Please check status of your HEAD and `origin/*` branches you're trying to push using `git log`.

Check out this answer how to remove the previous commits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/927386/430718

Comment: He needs to remove, not just revert, the previous commit that contains the large file.

Comment: That was it. Thanks for the help.